# Thunderbird 78 unable to decrypt multipart PGP email

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird

A colleague of mine is unable to read GPG-encrypted emails sent to them by another member of our team via our mailing list, saying this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGTD3.png). The recipient, unable to read emails, is using Thunderbird v78.3.1 with the built-in OpenPGP system, while the sender is using Thunderbird 68+Enigmail to encrypt their messages. Mozilla's extensive FAQ/HOWTO[2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-thunderbird-howto-and-faq) about their OpenPGP integration doesn't seem to have anything about this.

The sender is also using "Per-recipient rules" in Enigmail to specify which keys to encrypt the messages with.

Comment: Either the recipient can install the Enigmail add-on, which should work in Thunderbird 78.3.1, or the sender can send mail *without* using that add-on. If this is a corporate environment, then IT policy should be followed regarding encryption *standards*.